# Limit number of documents returned by MongoDB query optimization

Tags: mongodb

I have a really large collection. I want to get a sample of this collection like 4-5 documents based on an `exists` condition.

So my request looks like that :

```
db.myCollection.find({'my_field': {$exists: 1}}).limit(4)
```

That request is taking much time and I would like to know if there is a way to optimize it. In fact, I assume the find will first go through all the documents of the collection, find documents matching the `exists` query and then apply a limit to the cursor.

Is there a way that mongo would just look for 4 documents matching the request and then stop its research. That would speed up the request considerably.

Comment: The first and most useful thing to do is run an explain() on the query

Comment: MongoDB will (should) already be limiting the amount it actually searches for. A limit does actually work like that

Comment: I will try to look out at explain. But I believe limit query is something applied after the search on a cursor which does not work as I ask.